# A deamon for sending poem to clients based on KISS

Tags: c, socket, signal-handling

My code is about sending random poem from /etc/poem.conf to client using TCP sockets.

In this implementation my daemon have restart mechanism using SIGHUP signal and DEBUG mechanism using defining DEBUG macro during compilation.

My goals:

1. Simpler code
2. Less code
3. Cleaner code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <err.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#ifndef DEBUG
#define perror(msg) syslog(LOG_ERR, "%s: %s", msg, strerror(errno))
#define err(status, msg) perror(msg), _exit(status)
#endif

sigjmp_buf jmp;

void
sighub (__attribute__ ((unused)) int signo)
{
    siglongjmp (jmp, 1);
}

int
main()
{
    int sfd, cfd;
    char poem[BUFSIZ];
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    FILE *fpoem = NULL;

#ifndef DEBUG
    if (daemon (0, 0))
        err (1, "daemon");
#endif

    if (signal (SIGHUP, sighub))
        err (1, "signal");

    if ((sfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1)
        err (1, "socket");

    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);
    sa.sin_port = htons (1073);
    if (bind (sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof (sa)))
        err (1, "bind");

    if (listen (sfd, 10))
        err (1, "listen");

    if (sigsetjmp (jmp, 1))
        fclose (fpoem), close (cfd);

    if (! (fpoem = fopen ("/etc/poem.conf", "r")))
        err (1, "/etc/poem.conf");

    for (;;) {
        if ((cfd = accept (sfd, NULL, NULL)) == -1)
            perror ("accept");

        srand (time (NULL) + rand());
        fseek (fpoem, 0, SEEK_END);
        fseek (fpoem, rand() % ftell (fpoem), SEEK_SET);
        while (ftell (fpoem) > 0
                && fgetc (fpoem) != '\n')
            fseek (fpoem, -2, SEEK_CUR);

        fgets (poem, BUFSIZ, fpoem);
        write (cfd, poem, strlen (poem));
        close (cfd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using `sigaction` instead of `signal` which has highly variable behavior on different systems (which POSIX and ISO C allow). Also, `fclose` is generally not async-signal-safe, which makes calling it after your SIGHUP is received undefined. Consider what would happen if you were in the middle of a call to `malloc` (or a function that calls `malloc`), and then the SIGHUP+siglongjmp caused you to jump into `fclose` (which probably calls `free`) at the same time. `malloc`'s bookkeeping information would probably be in an inconsistent state leading to memory corruption when attempting free

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Make use of your operating system's facilities

A lot of the complexity in your code comes from wanting to call `daemon()` yourself, and then also wanting a way to run your code in the foreground. I strongly recommend that you just design your code as a foreground-running process, and then use whatever facilities your operating system provides for running it in the background if so desired.

Consider that most init systems allow you to start and manage a process running in the background, and will do a better job at this than you can from within your program. With systemd, you can create a .service file that will start your program automatically at boot, redirects all output to logfiles, can restart your program either manually or automatically when it crashes, synchronize with other services so it starts at the right time, and so on.

You can go further than that and even offload the TCP socket handling part to the init system. Again systemd has features for that, but even with the venerable SysV init system you have [inetd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inetd).

Of course, you can go even further; if you consider [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) to be part of the operating system, you can just replace your program with the command `shuf -n1 /etc/poem.conf`. This removes all code, so it perfectly fulfills the three goals you have.

## Consider binding to an IPv6 socket

On many operating systems it is possible to create a single IPv6 socket that can listen on both IPv4 and IPv6. On some this happens automatically, on others you might have to set the `IPV6_V6ONLY` socket option:

```
int option = 0;
setsockopt(sfd, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, &option, sizeof option);
```

## Unnecessary calls to `fseek()`

The first call to `fseek()` is only necessary once to get the length of the file, so it should be moved out of the `for`-loop. Also consider not scanning backwards for a newline, but scan forwards instead, this avoids the third call to `fseek()`. This also brings me to:

## Efficiently getting to the start of a new line

If you scan forward for a newline, then you don't need to read character by character in a `while`-loop, you can just call `fgets()` to discard one partial line, and then the second call will get you a complete line.

Of course, you might have an issue when you first seek into the middle of the last line in the file. In that case, consider wrapping to the start of the file and returning the first line:

```
fseek(fpoem, 0, SEEK_END);
long size = ftell(fpoem);

for (;;) {
    ...
    fseek(fpoem, rand() % size, SEEK_SET); // seek to random position
    fgets(poem, BUFSIZ, fpoem); // discard partial line
    fgets(poem, BUFSIZ, fpoem); // read full line

    if (feof(fpoem)) {
        fseek(fpoem, 0, SEEK_SET); // seek to start
        fgets(poem, BUFSIZ, fpoem); // read first line
    }
    ...
}
```

Of course, you could also just read the poem into an array of strings at the beginning of your program, this would avoid the overhead later on.

## Missing error handling

You are checking for errors for most things, except when reading a random line and sending it to the peer. Consider that all calls to `fseek()`, `fgetc()`, `fgets()` and `write()` can fail, either because of a permanent error or because of something like `EINTR`.

## Possibility of partial reads and writes

What if your poem contains a line equal to or longer than `BUFSIZE`? In that case, `fgets()` will still succeed, but read only the first `BUFSIZ - 1` characters. Check if the last character in the string is a newline to verify if a whole line was read.

A call to [`write()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) might write less than you told it to. This is something you should handle by checking the return value, and in case of a partial write, retry sending the remaining part, and so on in a loop until everything has been sent or a permanent failure happens. Alternatively, consider using [`fdopen()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fdopen.3p.html) to get a `FILE *` handle for the socket, so you can just call `fputs()` and not worry about these details.

## Beware of corner cases

What if /etc/poem.conf exists but is empty? What if the last line doesn't contain a newline? What if an I/O error happens in the `while`-loop and? What if `SIGHUP` is sent right after `sigsetjmp()` but before you even opened `fpoem` (and `cfd` is still uninitialized)? Make sure you think about corner cases, and adress all of them.